# runic characters not pasting correctly after passing through (win)clip.exe and nothing through utf8clip.exe

Tags: utf-8, lua, macros, clipboard, paste

so im using luamacros to make some different scripts for my 2nd keyboard however when trying to make a runic keyboard I've run into the issue of none of the programs features being able to send the text i want to other programs, I've done this once before sadly that hdd got trashed and didn't back it up, i got it to function using utf8clip before.

(win)clip.exe does paste something at least while utf8clip.exe doesn't paste anything however clip just pastes "ß¢Æ" instead of "ᛒ" when pasting into notepad(++), discord, ect.

my code as it stands rn, ive been using control+v as it produces the same output my paste function will.

```
-- assign logical name to macro keyboard
lmc_assign_keyboard('MACROS');

--Initialize global vars
currentname = 1
names = {"Runic letters and digraphs", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}
namez = {"Runic words", "2b", "3b", "4b", "5b", "6b", "7b", "8b", "9b", "10b"}
max_state = 10 --can be infinite but please try to keep it as small as possible and just make other scripts for more so you dont press tab 500 times.
state = 1
sideb = 0
say = lmc_say -- condensing code

-- Functions
function N_A (btn) -- condensing code
  print('Not yet assigned: ' .. btn)
end
function Paste ()
  lmc_sleep(100)
  lmc_send_input(9, 0, 0)
  lmc_sleep(50)
  lmc_send_input(86, 0, 0)
  lmc_sleep(50)
  lmc_send_input(86, 0, 2)
  lmc_send_input(9, 0, 2)
end

-- define callback for whole device
lmc_set_handler('MACROS',function(button, direction)
  if (direction == 1) then return end  -- ignore down
  if (button == 17) then if (sideb == 0) then say(names[currentname]) print(state .. "_" .. sideb .. ": " .. names[currentname]) else say(namez[currentname]) print(state .. "_" .. sideb .. ": " .. namez[currentname]) end --say name of current keyboard and print info to consol
  elseif (button == 9) then state = state + 1 if (state > max_state) then state = 1 end currentname = state --state switcher
  elseif (button == 16) then if (sideb == 0) then sideb = 1 else sideb = 0 end --side switcher
  elseif (state == 1) then if (sideb == 0) then
    if (button == 65) then io.popen('winclip','w'):write("ᚪ"):close()
    elseif (button == 66) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛒ"):close()
    elseif (button == 67) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᚳ"):close()
    elseif (button == 68) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛞ"):close()
    elseif (button == 69) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛖ"):close()
    elseif (button == 70) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᚠ"):close()
    elseif (button == 71) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᚷ"):close()
    elseif (button == 72) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᚺ"):close()
    elseif (button == 73) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛁ"):close()
    elseif (button == 74) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛄ"):close()
    elseif (button == 75) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛣ"):close()
    elseif (button == 76) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛚ"):close()
    elseif (button == 77) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛗ"):close()
    elseif (button == 78) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᚾ"):close()
    elseif (button == 79) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᚩ"):close()
    elseif (button == 80) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛈ"):close()
    elseif (button == 81) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛩ"):close()
    elseif (button == 82) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᚱ"):close()
    elseif (button == 83) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛋ"):close()
    elseif (button == 84) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛏ"):close()
    elseif (button == 85) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᚢ"):close()
    elseif (button == 86) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᚡ"):close()
    elseif (button == 87) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᚹ"):close()
    elseif (button == 88) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛪ"):close()
    elseif (button == 89) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᚤ"):close()
    elseif (button == 90) then io.popen('utf8clip','w'):write("ᛎ"):close() end

    else
      N_A(button)
    end
  else
    N_A(button)
  end
end)
```

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `"ᛒ".encode('utf-8').decode('cp437')` returns `ß¢Æ` …

Comment: You need to invoke `chcp 65001` in the console before pasting UTF-8 text.

Comment: @ESkri idk if or how id do it correctly, but currently through some more google searches i've found something that at least gets me somewhere different, its not pasting the character but it is pasting "Active code page: 65001"
`io.popen('chcp 65001 | clip <' .. char):close()`
lua's not my stongsuit and not many people doing what i am it seems.